# How to handle any event itself in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I need to run some function for every event from client in server node.js/socket.io
This is about calculate average time between events so I can detect spamers.

Any ideas? In docs I didn't find it. Something like:

```
socket.onAnyEvent( function() {
 //do things
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good thread: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/434 specifically you can extend the emitter.